# Can you "Force Choke" yourself to death?

Tags: star-wars, sith

Whether or not you can actually choke yourself to death has been gone over many times, and the general consensus is that you are unable to kill yourself this way. Fast forward to a galaxy far, far away. One of the powers we most commonly associate with the dark side of the force is the iconic "Force Choke," the ability to lift (not sure if Vader was special, but I can't remember another time I saw someone lifted off the ground) and strangle someone just by clenching your fist.

What if you, as a Sith, hated everything, especially yourself, and decided one day to end it? Granted there are much faster ways (quick one-two with the ol' lightsaber or maybe being [tickled with spooky lightning](https://youtu.be/lz8z_9g9Dbs?t=1m53s)) to end your life, but for some reason you're adamant on choking to death. I ask out of curiosity as Anakin released his grip on Padmé prematurely (if memory serves) which gave her enough time to name her children before popping her clogs. Whether she actually died from "losing the will to live" or not I'm unsure of.

Comment: you would probably also pass out, and loose grip of the force. hence stopping the force choke.

Comment: Tickle with spooky lightening seems spooky though.

Comment: @Himarm I understand that which is why I cited Anakin choking Padme and my uncertainty on the actual cause of her death :)

Comment: @ConnorSpencerHarries i think your just miss understanding, anikin stopped choking her  while he was still in front of her after he came to his senses(a little bit).

Comment: @Himarm I'm aware of that. Despite the release she could have still been suffering from the effects of it. I don't have any information to cite regarding the after effects of being force-choked though. There are enough wild theories to suggest she didn't simply lose the will to live as she still believed Anakin could be redeemed which takes me back to thinking about what actually killed her.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76856/what-did-padm%C3%A9-die-of the choking could have damaged her throat, but the force was no longer actively choking her. you could conceivably do similar damage to yourself its just usually not in lethal quantities before you pass out. obviously if he wanted to he could have used the force to break her neck, or to break her trechea which if done to yourself probably would kill you should you not get medical attention

Comment: “Why are you Force-choking yourself? Why are you Force-choking yourself?” “Oh Ani!”

Comment: I'm left wondering if you're working on a very specific erotic fanfic

Comment: @Richard sorry to disappoint, two of my friends (who will most likely be less than delighted to read this) were talking about using force choke in kinky ways. I was going through star wars stuff at the time and began to ponder. :P

Comment: Why would you need to? Aren't you always within range of yourself?

Comment: If you could, then David Carradine might still be with us.

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/682/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Force Grip is, technically, not a dark side power. It is Force-based telekinesis, a power all Force-sensitives are capable of. In this, it is the use of Force push on one's breathing apparatus in all directions, essentially constricting airflow and causing suffocation.

That is also how physical choking works. The only benefit is that Force Grip can be used outside melee range and leaves no fingerprints (which is beneficial because...you know).

The reason why committing suicide with Force Grip won't work is the same as that for physical self-choking. Both acts require conscious control of your hands/the Force throughout the act to maintain the required amount of strength. As you suffocate, your consciousness slowly fades out from a lack of air, and your mind slowly loses control of your hands/the Force, which in turn gradually loses its grip until the airflow returns to normal and you return to full life.

If you are able to keep your respiratory system choked without losing strength, then sure you can die from choking yourself, physically or otherwise. But that normally doesn't happen.

Things like lightning and lightsaber decapitation work because they happen faster than your loss of control can stop it. A strong enough current can short-circuit your heart before your brain is fried. Momentum keeps a lightsaber going even if you let go.

Source: Science!

Comment: i upvoted because you have 4.999 rep ._.

Comment: And now he's OVER FIVE THOUSA... wait... wrong setting full of super powers.

Comment: And this isn't even his final form.

Answer (score 3):

> [...] it is vital to distinguish between air and blood chokes. [...] if the airway rather than the carotid arteries is blocked, the subject cannot breathe, but his brain is still perfused with blood and he will remain conscious and may continue to struggle for a minute or more; he will lose consciousness only when the oxygen in the circulating blood is consumed and he collapses from hypoxia. **Even if the hold is released at this point, the blood circulating through the brain contains no oxygen, and consequently the subject may not regain consciousness** or resume spontaneous breathing.

*from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chokehold#Use_in_law_enforcement_.28Lateral_Vascular_Neck_Restraint.29)*

So if the force-choke ends once you lose consciousness, that may be too late. I guess it depends on how close to unconsciousness you can get while maintaining the force choke, which might be longer compared to hands, as no physical muscles are involved.

Comment: Damn, +1 for moar science AND the xkcd haha

Answer (score 0):

a powerful force user can use the force grip to such a level as to instantly kill his or her target so there should be no difference here. if a sith wants to die and uses the force grip to his or her maximum ability and he or she has the skill to instantly kill then yes it would be possible