# Did this Voyager character take his own life?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

**Note:** For those who are interested in *Voyager* but haven't seen the final episode, I've taken the liberty of spoiler-blocking most of this question.

---

The final episode of *Star Trek: Voyager* begins in the year 2404,

> 10 years after Voyager's return to the Alpha Quadrant, where it had spent 23 years.

A little later in the episode, we learn that

> Chakotay had died

in the year 2394.

> [image]

Much later in the episode,

> Admiral Janeway explains to her past self that Seven of Nine had died in transit through the Delta Quadrant and that Chakoteya "was never the same" after Seven's death.

Of course,

> these deaths end up being erased by Admiral Janeway's actions, which bring Voyager back to the Alpha Quadrant after only 7 years instead of 23.

**In the original timeline, prior to Admiral Janeway's actions, did**

> **Chakotay take his own life? (He would have only been 65, which is still fairly young by 24th Century standards.)**

The [Memory Alpha entry on the episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Endgame_%28episode%29) only makes the following vague, uncredited comment on the matter:

> The only thing that will make him keep his will to live after that [Seven's death] will be getting Voyager home. But once that has been done, he will not live long, dying well before his time.

Comment: The website should create a button you can click that instantly removes all spoilers.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon [waves wand] [Your wish is granted.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7897/31394)

Comment: He died of [a broken heart](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76856/what-did-padm%C3%A9-die-of)

Comment: @RedCaio : But surely a 20 cc dose of [inaprovaline](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Inaprovaline) would prevent that from happening.

Comment: @RedCaio - He was never the same after she died, that doesn't mean that he died of a broken heart.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer (with a lot of backup info) is: no, he died because of 'a broken heart'

Stress-induced cardiomyopathy is a real thing, according to several sources, including the American Heart Association. Although in a future universe that can even cure the common cold, it would be possible to better diagnose this and treat it. But for story purposes, it was much more dramatic and interesting that the viewers learn that Chakotay had fallen so much for Seven, that it broke him when she died.

Source: [Is Broken Heart Syndrome Real](http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/Conditions/More/Cardiomyopathy/Is-Broken-Heart-Syndrome-Real_UCM_448547_Article.jsp#.Wc15dmhSx3g)

Comment: Even in the future, the patient has to participate in the treatment. If someone makes up their mind to not go on living, there's still not much technology can do.

Comment: Ooh, yeah, good point. @ChrisB.Behrens. So without having to try to explain whether they had the technology to properly diagnose and treat, the doctor would still need consent of the patient.

Comment: I would imagine, furthermore, that Chakotay left Starfleet immediately upon returning home...he could have literally walked out into the desert to die. I've seen it in real life.

Comment: Where are you getting this information from? Is this just your own headcanon "*what happened next...*"?