# Is there any procedure to be followed when an half-elf gives up immortality?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, hobbits

I went through the following questions, [Why can Arwen decide her mortality?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31345/why-can-arwen-decide-her-mortality). It explains who can give up immortality. I would like to know if Tolkien had ever mentioned a procedure/ritual that has to be performed to give up immortality or it's just a decision in mind to give it up?

Secondly can this decision be reversed?

Comment: You have to turn in your badge and your gun.

Comment: @Richard of course, no hero ever achieves anything *until* they've turned in their badge and gun...

Comment: @aakashm - Dammit, Arwen. I told you not to get involved!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no mention of any kind of magic procedure, spell, incantation, etc. needed. Half-Elves are simply born with the option to make a one-time-only choice between immortality or mortal life with an unknown afterlife.

Comment: It's worth adding that this only applies to Earendil, Elwing and their descendents.  Other Half-Elves, such as the children of Imrazor and Mithrellas, don't get to choose: they're Men.

Comment: That is the sole reason I added the other question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31345/why-can-arwen-decide-her-mortality